# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, properties, webdriver

When I try to do code shown below I get error :

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
email2_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").text()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

...implies that your program have invoked a `function()` which is actually a `property`.

As per [selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) **`text`** is a `property`.

So, you can't invoke `text()` as a function. Hence you see the error.

### Solution

You can use either of the following solutions:

- Use [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) *property*:

  ```
  email2_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").text
  ```
- Use [`get_attribute("innerHTML")`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method:

  ```
  email2_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```

Comment: second method with get_atribute does same thing as just text?

Comment: @szymond45 Yes, imo, `get_attribute("innerHTML")` is much more promising.

Answer (score 5):

`text` is a property, not a function. Use it without `()`

```
element.text
```

As a side note, absolute `xpath` `"/html/body/..."` is a bad approach, it makes fragile locator. You should try locating the elements by unique attribute (`id`, `name`, `class` etc), or atleast relative `xpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find_element(By.XPATH, "class name")
```

Refer this documentation link

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements